# Material UI - Render / Open Menu Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to render a Material UI Menu for each of my JSX Button Elements.

Right now all of my Menu Items are stacked over each other. I would be able to only show the Menu
which relates to the Button that has been clicked.

[See it in Action](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-render-menu-507zt?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const menuOptions = [
    { id: 0, name: "Remove", method: "remove" },
    { id: 1, name: "Duplicate", method: "duplicate" },
    { id: 2, name: "New", method: "addNew" }
  ];

  const [addressInputFields, setAddressInputFields] = useState([
    { firstName: "", lastName: "" },
    { firstName: "", lastName: "" },
    { firstName: "", lastName: "" },
    { firstName: "", lastName: "" }
  ]);

  const handleMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {addressInputFields.map((input, index) => (
        <span key={index}>
          <button type="button" name="address" onClick={handleMenu}>
            ShowMenu
          </button>
          <Menu
            id="option-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleMenuClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "left"
            }}
            getContentAnchorEl={null}
          >
            <span>Menu Index: {index}</span>
            {menuOptions.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.id}>{option.name}</MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Menu>
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track the currently opened `Menu` by its `index`, then only render the menu with the `open` props set to `true` based on both `Boolean(anchorEl)` and the open index like below:

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

// track with menu should be opened
const [openIndex, setOpenIndex] = useState(-1);

const handleMenu = (index) => (event) => {
  setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  setOpenIndex(index); // set current menu index to open
};

const handleMenuClose = (event) => {
  setAnchorEl(null);
};

return (
  <div>
    {addressInputFields.map((input, index) => (
      <span key={index}>
        <button
          name="address"
          // handleMenu now need the index context to know which menu to open
          onClick={handleMenu(index)}
        >
          ShowMenu
        </button>
        <Menu
          // only render currently open menu
          open={Boolean(anchorEl) && index === openIndex}
          onClose={handleMenuClose}
          {...props}
        >
          <span>Menu Index: {index}</span>
          {menuOptions.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.id}>{option.name}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Menu>
      </span>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67211084/material-ui-render-open-menu-dynamically]

Comment: Great Idea and logically great!